# Can I use subjunctive when something is possible?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, subjunctive-mood

To my understanding when expressing something is not fact I should use subjunctive, e.g.

> Without your instruction, we would be working now.

I'm wondering if I can use subjunctive to express something that is possible for being a polite way.

In my case, I'd like to reply to the recruiting manager like this:

> If I was fortunate to get this job, ...

Is it ok to say like this?

Comment: No, you have to say "If I were ...", and your first sentence is not in subjunctive form.

Comment: And I would usually include "enough": "If I *were* fortunate *enough* to get this job, ..."

Comment: Necessity is not necessary for use of the subjunctive. "If I were home right now, I'd be late for work." It surely is possible that I could be at home right now. Also, the subjunctive is on it's way out of fashion (if not already).

Comment: Not even worth talking about, really. It's never been common outside idioms, and people get the idea that it's required because they've been fed the usual line that it's like Latin, where it **was** required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subjunctive tense only exists inside of a conditional/dependent clause:

"If I **were** instructed, I wouldn't be working now."
"Our work demands that she **instruct** us."
"If I **were** fortunate *enough* to get the job, I could pay my rent."

It doesn't matter whether it's likely or not.

Comment: There is no subjunctive tense. Subjunctive, when it exists, is a Mood, not a Tense.

Comment: Cool! I did not know that.

Comment: And the subjunctive mood does not exist in English. There are a couple of constructions in English that are sometimes called "subjunctive" -- because they reminded 18th-century scholars of the Latin subjunctive -- but they don't really constitute a mood (or tense, or voice, or aspect).

Comment: Most of what I know about grammar I learned by studying Spanish and translating back to English. I didn't know a thing called "subjunctive" existed.

But, I am curious why you'd say that no such mood exists?

Are you saying that "If I were . . " is incorrect? Or simply that it doesn't constitute a subjunctive mood in English?

Comment: I'm saying that the constructions mentioned do not constitute a Subjunctive mood, any more than _There_-Insertion sentences constitute an Existential mood. They're syntax, not morphology, and syntax works differently than morphology does.